# 'node: command not found' error only when running npm scripts

Tags: windows, npm, path

When running NPM scripts (such as `npm run start`), I get an error saying `node: command not found`. This does not happen when I run exactly the same command specified in package.json manually in the terminal (Windows Command Prompt as well as VSCode powershell).

I have ensured many times that the file path to the node.exe file is in my system PATH, as confirmed by the `node` command working outside of npm scripts.

As a simplified example, I can set the `test` script to `node .`, run `npm run test`, and the error occurs. When going to a command prompt and entering `node .` from the same directory, everything works fine.

After setting up a script that echoes the PATH variable, it seems that the path that NPM uses is different from my system's path, and therefore cannot find the node command. How can I ensure that npm scripts use the system path and recognize the 'node' command (aside from simply directly placing the path to the node.exe file in the script, since the same error happens with other npm commands such as `npm install`)?